# Sistema de recomendação com base em dados anteriormente registrados

Tags: machine-learning

Sou leigo em machine-learning comecei um curso na Alura sobre [sistema de classificação](https://www.alura.com.br/curso-online-introducao-a-machine-learning-com-classificacao) usando [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)  porém não resolve meu problema, eu gostaria de uma biblioteca para um **sistema de recomendação**, eu iria coletar dados relacionados a cada partida de um jogo eletronico e recomendar qual a melhor rota para o jogador seguir.

A lógica eu desenvolvo, apenas gostaria de alguma recomendação(Um Norte) de bibliotecas e/ou linguagens para desenvolver isso.

**EDIT:** Eu vou aplicar machine-learning num jogo, ao final de cada partida o jogador iria preencher dados como: onde ele caiu no mapa, quanto tempo ficou vivo, quantos jogadores ele matou e com quais armas **e principalmente em que posição ele ficou** na partida. Com isso eu iria treinar, analisar, ou seja lá o que for um algoritmo para dar dicas para ele por exemplo onde ele deveria cair, quais armas ele deveria usar e outras coisas.

Comment: Ao cidadão que pediu para fechar por "fora de escopo" leia as regras "mas se a sua pergunta tem a ver com...- ferramentas comuns entre programadores" … então este é o lugar certo para fazer sua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem certeza de que o seu problema é de recomendação? Encaixa-se em problemas de recomendação aqueles em que o número de itens que podem ser recomendados é muito grande e por isso não podem ser resolvidos de forma escalável por algoritmos de classificação comuns. No seu caso, me parece mais um problema de múltiplas classes, em que o número de rotas possíveis não é muito grande.

Para recomendação, uma abordagem comum é usar algoritmos baseados na decomposição em valores singulares da matriz de interações. Esse [pacote em R](https://github.com/dselivanov/reco) tem uma implementação bem legal de uma penca desses algoritmos. No Spark tem uma implementação de [ALS](https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/ml-collaborative-filtering.html) que parece ser bem escalável. Em python, também existem diversas opções. Eu gosto bastante do [LightFM](http://lyst.github.io/lightfm/docs/home.html). Mas também existe o [Surprise](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Caso contrário, a maioria dos algoritmos de classificação também possuem extensões para multiplas classes. Geralmente, é feito o chamado *One-vs-Rest*, treina-se um algoritmo para classificar cada classe versus as outras e depois é escolhida a classe com maior score.

Comment: Daniel, da uma olhada no meu edit, vê se fica mais claro para você o que eu pretendo fazer. De qualquer forma já agradeço pelo norte, vou pesquisar sobre os links que você me passou, já tinha ouvido falar de R, mas imaginava que era mais relacionado a estatistica(apesar de que da para aplicar também), da uma olhada no edit.

Comment: cara, infelizmente vou votar para fechar a sua pergunta. o que você precisa é tipo uma consultoria em análise de dados, uma boa resposta nao caberia no espaço que temos aqui no site.

Comment: A vontade, apenas preciso de um norte pois consigo aprender sozinho, precisava apenas alguma referencia para estudar e você ja respondeu, valeu